# Twitter Not working In my Project

Tags: android

I am implemented twitter integration into my android project the problem is the code working some times some times it's showing the error. I am not understanding what wrong with my code.Below is my code and log-cat errors.

consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_OAUTH_KEY,TWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET);

```
    provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

    mTwitterBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.twitterCheck);

    mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key);
    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);

    mTwitterBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
                postToTwitter = mTwitterBtn.isChecked();

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                        ShareApplicationTweeter.this, PostApplication.class);
                startActivity(shareIntent);

                // share("Hi", "Test");

            } else {
                mTwitterBtn.setChecked(false);
                mTwitter.authorize();
            }

        }
    });

    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        username = mTwitter.getUsername();
        username = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;
        mTwitterBtn.setText("  Twitter  (" + username + ")");
    }
```

04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.a1.buzzmob.ShareApplicationTweeter.onCreate(ShareApplicationTweeter.java:86)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-19 01:24:04.001: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 01:29:04.033: I/Process(545): Sending signal. PID: 545 SIG: 9

Thanks,
Murali.

Comment: USE SEARCH !!!!!!!! you've change ADT to 17 so check first result ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BNoClassDefFoundError%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+adt+17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your libraries to "libs" folder